# Spring Cloud Gateway Use predicate to check header authorization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

Is it possible to use the predicate section of the spring cloud gateway config to check the header authorization, my goal is to have some basic auth on one or more endpoints

I'm using application.yml for route configuration

```
cloud:
gateway:
  routes:
    - id: serviceRoute
      uri: http://service:8000
      predicates:
        - Path=/service/
        **- Header= ??** 
      filters:
        - name: CircuitBreaker
          args:
            name: slow
            fallbackUri: forward:/fallback/service
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out the syntax, will only route to service if both conditions are met

```
cloud:
gateway:
  routes:
    - id: serviceRoute
      uri: http://service:8000
      predicates:
        - Path=/service/
        - Header=Authorization, Basic password
      filters:
        - name: CircuitBreaker
          args:
            name: slow
            fallbackUri: forward:/fallback/service
```

Comment: Can you please add java config?

Answer (score 5):

The below is my sample based on [spring gateway sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-gateway-sample). If no header Authorization, access http://localhost:20000/, response code is 404. If add Authorization, reponse code is 405 which means access ok. Please change Path as your need.

main class defination

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.MapReactiveUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemogatewayApplication {

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.httpBasic().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/anything/**").authenticated()
                .anyExchange().permitAll()
                .and()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MapReactiveUserDetailsService reactiveUserDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("user").password("password").roles("USER").build();
        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemogatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-sample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-cloud-gateway-sample</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Cloud Gateway</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

application.yml defination

```yaml
server:
  port: 20000

spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: serviceRoute
        uri: http://www.sohu.com
        predicates:
        - Path=/
        - Header=Authorization, Bearer [0-9a-zA-Z-.]*
```